# Do pattern matching in scheme

Tags: regex, scheme, pattern-matching

Does anyone have an idea how to match the pattern `(entity ?e0 . ?attrs)` with `(entity e0 (prov:type "Revision")` ??? The number 0 in ?e0 can be any number 1, 2, 3 .....

The result after matching is `(?e0 . e0) (?attrs (prov:type "Revision"))`

I have tried this:

```
  (define clause-match
  (lambda (statement1 statement2)
    (match statement2 [(list 'entity ?(car (cdr statement1)) (cons (car (cdr statement1)) (car (cdr statement2))))] [list _ 'no])))
```

But I didn't succeed .....

Error:  `match: syntax error in pattern (car (cdr statement1))`

Please show me where I'm wrong and how to fix it!! Regular expression make me really confused ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(define (clause-match stmt)
  (match stmt
    [(list 'entity e0 attrs ...) 
     (list (list '?e0 e0) (cons '?attrs attrs))]
    [else #f]))
```

then

```
(clause-match '(entity e1 (prov:type "Revision")))
=> '((?e0 e1) (?attrs (prov:type "Revision")))

(clause-match '(entity e1 (prov:type "Revision") (one:two "Three")))
=> '((?e0 e1) (?attrs (prov:type "Revision") (one:two "Three")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(match statement2 
[
(list 'entity ?
     (car (cdr statement1)
) 
(cons (car (cdr statement1)
      ) (car (cdr statement2)))
] [list _ 'no]))
)
```

Your closing brackets and so on don't match up.
Fixing them should resolve the syntax error.

Comment: I didn't fix your statement, just pointed it out.
I find it a bit hard to read without context to figure out where which bracket needs to come (as I don't know which language you are writing in your code in)

Comment: the language is scheme. And your code is actually wrong in syntax of `match` procedure

Comment: I just copied your code and expanded it so, basically your code is then wrong?

Comment: my code is wrong so i really need to fix it but your code doesn't fix the problem

Comment: As stated before, I was only pointing out that I expected your brackets aren't balanced. So recheck your syntax and try again.

Comment: ok, I checked and fixed, adding one more. and there are still an error